# What's wrong with this GROUP BY Query?

Tags: php, mysql

I can't seem to wrap my head around this; all resources I read show this should be ok:

```
'SELECT e.ID, e.EVENT_NAME, e.EVENT_DATE, v.VENUE_NAME, l.LOCATION, GROUP_CONCAT(ms.MUSIC_STYLE_NAME) as `Styles`'.
'FROM events AS e'.
'INNER JOIN venues as v ON e.VENUE_LOCATION = v.ID'.
'INNER JOIN locations AS l ON e.VENUE_LOCATION = l.ID'.
'INNER JOIN event_music_styles AS ems ON e.ID = ems.EVENT_ID'.
'INNER JOIN music_styles AS ms ON ms.ID = ems.MUSIC_STYLE_ID'.
'GROUP BY e.ID';
```

However...

> Invalid query: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near 'BY e.ID' at line 1

Comment: Your code sample is actually PHP but you did not consider that as a possible cause for the problem. Next time please print out the finished query string, and you'll see the issue! This isn't a MySQL problem.

Comment: Sorry Tomalak, I'll do that next time :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you miss spaces. Try

```
'SELECT e.ID, e.EVENT_NAME, e.EVENT_DATE, v.VENUE_NAME, l.LOCATION, GROUP_CONCAT(ms.MUSIC_STYLE_NAME) as `Styles`'.
     ' FROM events AS e'.
     ' INNER JOIN venues as v ON e.VENUE_LOCATION = v.ID'.
     ' INNER JOIN locations AS l ON e.VENUE_LOCATION = l.ID'.
     ' INNER JOIN event_music_styles AS ems ON e.ID = ems.EVENT_ID'.
     ' INNER JOIN music_styles AS ms ON ms.ID = ems.MUSIC_STYLE_ID'.
     ' GROUP BY e.ID';
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what language it is, but it seems

`'INNER JOIN music_styles AS ms ON ms.ID = ems.MUSIC_STYLE_ID'.
         'GROUP BY e.ID'`

would result in

`'INNER JOIN music_styles AS ms ON ms.ID = ems.MUSIC_STYLE_IDGROUP BY e.ID'`

so the 'group' keyword cannot be recognized.

Answer (score 1):

Well,Try this

```
SELECT e.ID,
       e.EVENT_NAME,
       e.EVENT_DATE,
       v.VENUE_NAME,
       l.LOCATION,
       GROUP_CONCAT(ms.MUSIC_STYLE_NAME) as `Styles`
       FROM events as e
         INNER JOIN venues as v ON e.VENUE_LOCATION = v.ID
         INNER JOIN locations as l ON e.VENUE_LOCATION = l.ID
         INNER JOIN event_music_styles as ems ON e.ID = ems.EVENT_ID
         INNER JOIN music_styles as ms ON ms.ID = ems.MUSIC_STYLE_ID
         GROUP BY e.ID;
```

Comment: @Tomalak I tried to remove the syntax error, Don't you see any changes made ?

Comment: Thank you for the answer Viswanathan :)

Comment: @pufAmuf Welcome anytime mate!